# How to merge two apa tables through papaja?

Tags: join, merge, r-markdown, papaja

I need help. I managed to have r tables in APA style using papaja in r markdown. But I need to merge them into one big table(It is going to be sociodemographics).

Sorry If I am not being clear but my situation is something like [image: in this picture].

It doesn't have to be done through papaja but it looks so simple because I have exact columns but I don't know why r doesn't let me merge them.

Comment: Can you provide the code (or a minimal example) with which you created tables 1 and 2? This would make it much easier to write a helpful and instructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a `list` of consistently structured `data.frame`s, `apa_table()` will merge them in one of two ways depending on the setting of `merge_method`. The following does what you are looking for, I believe.

```r
papaja::apa_table(
  list(
    Head = head(cars, 3)
    , Tail = tail(cars, 3)
  )
  , merge_method = "indent"
)
```

In Markdown format the results looks as follows.

```
           speed   dist   
---------  ------  -------
Head                      
\ \ \ 1    4.00    2.00   
\ \ \ 2    4.00    10.00  
\ \ \ 3    7.00    4.00   
Tail                      
\ \ \ 48   24.00   93.00  
\ \ \ 49   24.00   120.00 
\ \ \ 50   25.00   85.00
```

(`\`  are non-breaking spaces used to indent the contents of the first column. Note that `merge_method = "table_spanner"` only works in **papaja** documents.)